# How to securely store user passwords for an external application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption

I'm building an application with Rails and will be pulling timesheets from [Harvest](http://www.getharvest.com/), a timetracking app. I'm using an API wrapper called [harvested](https://github.com/zmoazeni/harvested). To be able to interface with their API, I need to provide a subdomain, username and password.

Right now, I'm just storing the passwords as plain strings and have not done any encryption. Would like to encrypt them before storing in the DB. If I encrypt the passwords before storing, can I still use the encrypted password for authenticating with the Harvester API?

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, use OAuth. https://github.com/harvesthq/api/blob/master/Authentication/OAuth%202.0.md

Comment: never ever store passwords in plaintext! EVER!

Comment: That's why I was asking how I should do this. The app is still not in production so it shouldn't be a problem just yet.

Answer (score 2):

OAuth exists for this very reason.  Storing plaintext is obviously a bad idea, but storing something encrypted that you then decrypt is ALSO a bad idea.

Modern password flows use one-way encryption: encrypting the password and then comparing it an *already encrypted* value in the database.  This allows use of algorithms that can encrypt easily but are essentially impossible to decrypt.  Using an algorithm that allows your application to easily decrypt database fields will also allow an attacker to do the same.

With a one-way flow (encryption only), even if a user gets ahold of your encrypted passwords, they are unusable since anything entered in the password box will be passed through the encryption again before testing for validity.

**TL;DR**
Use OAuth as someone else pointed out: https://github.com/harvesthq/api/blob/master/Authentication/OAuth%202.0.md

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, tyler. I ended up solving this a different way though. I just encrypted the password into an auth_string that the Harvester API was expecting. I monkey-patched the gem I used so that I could pass the auth_string instead of username and the unencrypted password.